# PHPExcel : Parsing XLSX files with X namespace

Tags: php, phpexcel, xlsx, import-from-excel

I am using the latest master of PHPExcel (most recent commit March 28th 2015) to parse an xlsx file for a client, the following code reads the file without complaining but finds no data (the only output I currently get is NULL):

```
<?php

    include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

    $inputFileName = 'foo.xlsx';

    try {
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($inputFileName); 
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName); 
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print_r('Error loading file "' . pathinfo($inputFileName, 
                PATHINFO_BASENAME) . '": ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheetByName("Orders");

    var_dump($sheet);           

?>
```

The workbook definition inside the xlsx file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>    
    <x:workbook xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
        <x:fileVersion appName="xl" lastEdited="4" lowestEdited="4" rupBuild="4506" />
        <x:workbookPr defaultThemeVersion="124226" />
        <x:bookViews>
            <x:workbookView xWindow="480" yWindow="345" windowWidth="24495" windowHeight="11955" />
        </x:bookViews>
        <x:sheets>
            <x:sheet name="Orders" sheetId="4" r:id="relId4" />
        </x:sheets>
        <x:calcPr calcId="125725" />
</x:workbook>
```

I think it's not working out that there's an "Orders" sheet because it's looking for "sheets" in the default namespace rather than the "x" namespace. Sorry if terminology is a bit gibberish there but hopefully you can see what I mean.

There is definitely data there, in that worksheet, because I can open the file in LibreOffice and see it.

Is there a way to get PHPExcel to use the x namespace as the default or in some other way get it to load worksheets defined in this way?

In my quest to find out I found a bug report from 2010[1](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/workitem/13473) regarding a similar issue which doesn't seem to have been addressed.

Comment: There isn't any way to get PHPExcel to use the `x` namespace until I rewrite it to do so

Comment: Thanks Mark, I was wondering if I should go and write a new reader for those kinds of spreadsheet rather than do the horrid hack I had to do for the client as time was tight.

Comment: You're right that a couple of these with different (to those used by MS Excel itself) namespaces have cropped up recently.... I'm already rewriting the XML-based Readers to use XMLReader rather than SimpleXML, which is taking a surprising amount of effort, and trying to address the namespacing issues as part of that work, but it's slow progress

Comment: This issue is tracked under https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/571 - @Mark, any progress to share during the last year? :)

Answer (score 4):

This issue is tracked at https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/571

What follows is a workaround, it is ugly but may help until this issue has been fixed...

Create a new class `PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007_XNamespace.php`:

```
<?php

class PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007_XNamespace extends PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007
{

    public function securityScan($xml)
    {
        $xml = parent::securityScan($xml);
        return str_replace(['<x:', '</x:'], ['<', '</'], $xml);
    }

}
```

Then load your excel file using this reader:

```
$excelReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007_XNamespace();
$objPHPExcel = $excelReader->load($inputFileName);
```

UPDATE: A more general issue for handling of non-standard namespaces has been filed and an updated workaround (covering the "d" namespace as well) is found at https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/1187#issuecomment-295032648